# Limit text length based on fitting text inside fixed width and height box

Tags: javascript, html, web, textarea

I am writting script which limits entered text inside by checking if text fits inside div box which height & width is fixed if not tries to lower font size and then again checks then reached minimum font size it limits text inside textarea. I have accomplished this but it sometimes reaches limit with over height and it do not allow overwrite text then selected.

Here is my script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var notebox_tmp = $(".notebox_tmp");
    var maxHeight = 120;
    var minFontSize = 25;

    notebox_tmp.css("font-size","50px");
    notebox_tmp.text($(this).val());
    var currentHeight = notebox_tmp.height();
    var currentFontSize = parseInt(notebox_tmp.css("font-size"),10);
    while (currentHeight > maxHeight && currentFontSize > minFontSize) {
        notebox_tmp.css("font-size", currentFontSize);
        currentFontSize -= 0.25;
        currentHeight = notebox_tmp.height();
    }
    if (currentFontSize <= minFontSize) { 
      e.preventDefault();
    }
};

$("textarea").keypress(onEdit);
```

Here is my current script demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/6pfCM/9/

Comment: Why do you have to accomplish the limit on the textarea in such a complicated manner? A simple `maxlength` attribute would do this. Even if `maxlength` is not what you want, it's still unnecessary to change the font size to detect the length. A much shorter simple JavaScript snippet could do something similar. Refer to other questions on StackOverflow for more efficient ways of accomplishing this.

Comment: The problem is that textarea is just for changing text but that text fits in one box which by client needs to resize text until minimum to fit more text its starts with 50px down to 25px

Comment: Why don't you edit your question and add that extra info?

Comment: Gotta say I didn't have any trouble understanding his question.