# Text from textarea to div with limited width and height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, textarea

I need to put text from textarea into a div limited by width and height.
Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ptCoder/8XL7n/30/

For example: I have a div width 100px and max height 100px. I need to enter text in textarea and this text will be appear in div box.

Here is another example but don’t work well: [Limit text length based on fitting text inside fixed width and height box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306083/limit-text-length-based-on-fitting-text-inside-fixed-width-and-height-box)

I need to have implementation like delete, backspace and copy/paste.

I have tried prevent the height size with this code:

```
if (currentHeight >= window.maxHeight) {  
    //alert('sim');
    var $th = $(this);
    $th.val($th.val().replace(/./, function(str) {
        return '';
    }));
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

But I have bugs with delete, backspace and copy-paste, etc…

The other problem is text disappearing in textarea...

Comment: can you please explain what are you trying to do ? Whats your motive?

Comment: Why don't you use `contenteditiable`?

Comment: Why do people run away after posting questions ... I am more excited to sort the issue than she/he is to get it sorted .. :D :P

Comment: My motive is put text from a textarea into a partial space of a html canvas. I'm limited to this space. Do you understand? Sorry my English.

Comment: @BhumiSinghal, In my case I'm limited and contenteditiable is not an alternative :/

Comment: Ohk! So what you need is that as you are typing in textarea... you restrict the typing when the width and height of the text in textarea becomes the same as that of the div?

Comment: The size of the textarea may be different. I just want to restrict the size of the text in div. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you just use max-width and max-height?

```
#target {
    max-width:200px;
    max-height:200px;
}
```

This should limit the size of your target.

Comment: @ptCoder Perhaps you could expand the parameters of your question then? Is limiting the size of the box all you want to accomplish? Or more than that?

Comment: Thank you for all.
Basically I need to write text in textarea so that it does not exceed a predefined size in div.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#inputData').keydown(function(){
    limitText($('#inputData'),100,100);
    });

    $('#inputData').keyup(function(){
        limitText($('#inputData'),100,100);
        });
});

function limitText(limitField, limitCount, limitNum) {
    if (limitField.val().length > limitNum) {
        limitField.val(limitField.val().substring(0, limitNum));
    } else {
        limitCount=limitNum - limitField.val().length;
    }
}
</script>
    <textarea maxlength="100" class="mycss" id="inputData" name="data" spellcheck=false wrap="physical"></textarea>
```